# How to reference an existing object in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, object, reference, controls

How do you reference an existing object in vb.net?

To describe my problem more specifically, I have my main form `Form1` that loads when I start the application. `Form1` has a datagridview `dgv1`. I have another form `form2` in the project with a bunch of textboxes. On clicking a button on `Form1` I create an instance of `form2`. From `form2` how do I reference the existing `form1` to populate `dgv1` with input from the texboxes on `form2`?

Comment: Consider adding methods to your forms so FormA can tell FormB to populate *its own* controls.

Comment: Why don't you try `module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference-to-`Form1` to `Form2`. Use the `Me` keyword to get a reference to the object currently executing:

In `Form1.vb`:

```
Sub Form1_OpenForm2()

    Dim form2 As New Form2()
    form2.AcceptForm1( Me )
    form2.Show()
End Sub
```

In `Form2.vb`:

```
Private _form1 As Form1

Public Sub AcceptForm1(form1 As Form1)
    _form1 = form1
End Sub
```

Comment: Windows Forms controls are not Public by default, though, so he'll also need to make controls he needs in Form1 public or write Public Properties for the specific things he wants to be able to do.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - controls are `Friend` by default so should be fine to access from another form

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix: You can access a control on `Form1` *directly* from `Form2`

So if you have `DataGridView1` on `Form1`, in the `Form2` code you can access it by using `Form1.DataGridView1`

Note: this is not a good design, because you are tightly coupling your two forms, you would be better to pass a reference to a DataGridView into Form2 rather than updating it directly

in the Constructor of Form2 force it to pass your reference:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private _dgv As DataGridView
    Public Sub New(dgv As DataGridView)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        'ensure we have a value object
        If dgv Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("DataGridView")
        _dgv = dgv
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmRibbonTest_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Dim rect = RibbonControl1.ClientRectangle
        DataGridView1.Location = New Point(rect.X, rect.Y)
        DataGridView1.Height = rect.Height
        DataGridView1.Width = rect.Width
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then when you create form2 from form1, use your reference like this:

```
 Dim f2 = New Form2(Me.DataGridView1)
 f2.Show()
```